# Assembly instruction set issue

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a bit of problem what instruction set I need to use when I am using unoptimized instructions that the compiler thing is great.

I have this a void function like this:

```
void feed(void)
{
 IWDG_ReloadCounter();
}
```

Here are the instructions.

```
//PUSH REGISTER ONTO STACK
push {r7}
//ADD
add r7, sp, #0

//???
mov.w r3, #12288
//MOVE TOP
movt r3, #16384
//MOVE 16-BIT CONSTANT
movw r2, #43690
//STORE REGISTER WORD
str r2, [r3, #0]

//MOVE
mov sp, r7
//POP REGISTER FROM STACK
pop {r7}
//BRANCH INDIRECT
bx lr
```

Can understand which of them to use. Anyone have some words of wisdom.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The compiler has generated 9 instructions. Even assuming you can improve on that, the improvement will be unnoticeable unless you run the code continuously for weeks.

Comment: The thing I am trying to do is to get this to work because it doesnt. The IWDG_ReloadCounter is to feed a watchdog so the system dont restart. And when i try to use the generated assembly for this function nothing is happening. Its a void so i dont need to thing about the stack so wich of these more than the ones that push on stack and pop should i remove.

Comment: You need to reword your question, then. It's not at all clear what your objective is, and there's nowhere near enough information to help diagnose.

Comment: Big thankgs. I solved it. Because the function is made with a pointer i only needed to use there instructions:

**mov.w r3, #12288
movt r3, #16384
movw r2, #43690
str r2, [r3, #0]**

Comment: @glts When you're removing a wrong tag, make sure you leave the question with enough correct tags.  e.g. `[arm]` - most mis-tagged `[stm]` questions were using it for the name of a vendor of ARM chips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function is made with a pointer I only needed to use these instructions:

```
mov.w r3, #12288 
movt r3, #16384 
movw r2, #43690 
str r2, [r3, #0]
```